# Delete core data entry cannot invoke 'deleteObject' with an argument list of '([AnyObject]?)'

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate

When I try to remove a core data entry from my project, I bump into the error

```
cannot invoke 'deleteObject' with an argument list of '([AnyObject]?)'
```

I think this basically asking me to cast the object but when I try this, I get the same error.  My code is as follows:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
var error:NSError? = nil
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: projectEntityName)
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "projectName = %@", projectName)
                request.predicate = pred
let objects = context?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
if let objectList = objects {
   for thisProject in objectList {
      thisProject.deleteObject(objects)
   }
}
appDelegate.saveContext()
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your variables mixed up.  `deleteObject` is a method of the NSManagedObjectContext, and you pass the object to be deleted as the parameter:

```
if let objectList = objects {
   for thisProject in objectList {
      context!.deleteObject(thisProject)
   }
}
```

Comment: Cheers... This basically solved it for me.  There was just a casting needed to complete the delete object line...                                                 context!.deleteObject(thisProject as! NSManagedObject)

Answer (score 0):

Use `as`.

```
thisProject.deleteObject(objects as! [type])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'd tried tried this already by using... thisProject.deleteObject(objects) as! NSManagedObject but I still get the same error